# Library output with css in user land and library Webpack

Tags: webpack, code-duplication

Currently using webpack to build a library, The library contains a couple UI-Components, these UI components depend on a couple styles from the library. However the same styles are also the ones that are exposed to users so they can access and style with. Whats the best way to prevent duplication of css as I don't want the user to have two copies of the styles(css) if they are using `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, `css-loader`, `style-loader`, etc.

How to integrate the styles with library UMD output webpack build?

Comment: How do the components depend on the CSS? If you can decouple them, then that might help to avoid the issue. There's not enough information to say anything concrete.

Comment: The components use some of the styles to be rendered properly